# 'undefined' error in custome pipe in angular 4

Tags: angular, pipe

I have created a FlyingHeroesPipe pipe exactly like [this](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) tutorial.

but I see `TypeError: allHeroes is undefined` error in console. what should I do? I searched a lot on the net but all samples were the same as my custom pipe but they work for others except me. my angular version is 5.0.1

**Update**

my code:

**src/app/flying-heroes.component.html (flyers)**

`<div *ngFor="let hero of (heroes | flyingHeroes)">
  {{hero.name}}
</div>`

**src/app/flying-heroes.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { Flyer } from './heroes';

@Pipe({ name: 'flyingHeroes' })
export class FlyingHeroesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(allHeroes: Flyer[]) {
    return allHeroes.filter(hero => hero.canFly);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FlyingHeroesPipe ,
...
...
...

]
```

Comment: Please, share your code!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way (I'm basing it on your link since you provided no code)

```
transform(allHeroes: Flyer[]) {
  return allHeroes ? allHeroes.filter(hero => hero.canFly) : [];
}
```

It just says you don't have a list of heroes. So if you don't, return an empty array, otherwise, filter it !

Comment: I want to filter my list certainly and I am sure that allHeroes always has data @trichetriche

Comment: You may be sure, but if Angular tells you there's no data, then there's no data, whether you're sure or not ;) If the console says allHeroes is undefined, then it's undefined. You probably made a mistake somewhere, but it's hard to say without code.

Answer (score 0):

you must know that the inputs are not evaluated at the time of construction but rather in initialization phase.

then, in your component "flying-heroes" you sould initialize "heroes" with an empty array

```
@Compnent({...})
export class FlyinHeroesCompnent {
   @Input() heroes: Flyer[] = [];
   ...
}
```

Or in your Pipe, set a default value for arrgument

```
transform(allHeroes: Flyer[] = []) {
  return allHeroes.filter(hero => hero.canFly);
}
```

Personally I prefer the second way